# I'm not able to connect to SQL Server Express using JDBC with Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server (localhost) to be able to save information on the database however whenever I try to achieve so for some reason when I go from MainActivity.java to Main2Activity.java my application stops working for about 20 seconds then comes up with a toast message (connection refused) , please advise what am I doing wrong

Main2Activity.java

```
package com.example.omar.externaldatabaseconnection;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_name, et_age, et_address, et_email ,et_telephone;
Button btn_save;
DatabaseConnection db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}

et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
et_age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_age);
et_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_address);
et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
et_telephone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_telephone);
btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
db = (DatabaseConnection) getApplication();
db.open();

btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
db.save("insert into Employees values 
('"+et_name.getText().toString().trim()+"', 
'"+et_age.getText().toString().trim()+"', 
'"+et_address.getText().toString().trim()+"', 
'"+et_email.getText().toString().trim()+"', 
'"+et_telephone.getText().toString().trim()+"')");
finish();
}
});
}

}
```

DatabaseConnection.java

```
package com.example.omar.externaldatabaseconnection;

import android.app.Application;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;


public class DatabaseConnection extends Application {

Connection connection;
String url = "";
String DBName = "EmployeesDB";
String DBUserName = "PC NAME";
String DBPassword = "MSSQL Password";
String HostName = "10.0.2.2";
String Port = "MY PORT NUMBER";
Statement statement;

public void open(){
try {
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + HostName +":"+Port+";"+ "databaseName=" + 
DBName + ";user=" + DBUserName + ";password="+ DBPassword + " 
instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, DBUserName, DBPassword);
}
catch (Exception e){
Toast.makeText(this, e.getCause().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}

public void save (String sql){
try {
statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeQuery(sql);
}
catch (Exception ex){
Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sir android is a mobile platform and you just can't connect an android application with any database server i.e. Sql server, mysql or oracle directly, you have to create a local SQLITE database and populate it by fetching data from any of the above mention database servers through a WEB SERVICE again it's totally up to you if you choose php, asp , java etc for making your WEB Service. After you have populated your SQLITE database you will then be able to perform queries on local SQLITE database.

**In simple words WEB SERVICE is the bridge between android application and a database server and you have to use one.**

Comment: Thank you so much for the useful information however, the main reason that I was trying this approach that many videos on youtube say that using JDBC makes you be able to access the database the way I did it.